# How can I grep patterns only inside files with a specific file name?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, regex, wildcards

I spent plenty of time searching for an existing question about my issue but I falied to find any solution for this case in specific. I apologize in advance if there is an existing thread/question solving it, and would appreciate if anyone could point me forward.

I have to search a pattern (e.g. "GENE") among numerous files in a data system. However, the data set is named as follows:

```
foo_1549474392_93.nwk
foo_1549474392_93.ort.final.nwk
foo_1549474392_93.ort.nwk
foo_1549474392_93.ort_reroot.nwk
```

These are the text files for analysis n# 93. There are 550 in total. Thing is, I have to find the pattern **only** in the files named like "foo_1549474392_93.nwk"  (i.e.: anything + underscore + digit(s) + .nwk, with numbers going from 1 to 550, not 001 to 550). Everything else before the underline is irrelevant.

I have already tried this

```
grep "GENE" *'/d'.nwk
```

and many variations using [0-9] and so on.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: So you want to include `foo_1549474392_93.nwk` but exclude the others? and the `93` may be one, two, or three digits?

Comment: Yes, before the .nwk I need at least one digit. I came across with a solution by using grep "foo" *[0-9].nwk - worked all right for this case in specific. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search any file whose name matches anything + underscore + digits + .nwk, with the digits going from 1 to 550 and excluding 001, 551, etc, try:

```
shopt -s nullglob; grep GENE  *_{1..550}.nwk
```

Because `{1..550}` expands to the numbers that you want (and only the numbers you want),  the glob `*_{1..550}.nwk` will include only the files that you want.  To assure that all the files in the expansion actually exist in the directory, we set `nullglob` with  `shopt -s nullglob`.

Since you may not want the change in nullglob to affect other commands, it may be useful to use parens to put the command in a subshell.

```
(shopt -s nullglob; grep GENE  *_{1..550}.nwk)
```

The change in nullglob affects only the subshell (what's inside the parens) and not anything before or after.

#### Example

Let's create four files with `GENE`, two that match your filename criteria and two that don't:

```
$ echo GENE | tee bad_1224_01.nwk bad_3456_551.nwk good_23456_1.nwk good_763456_550.nwk
GENE
$ ls
bad_1224_01.nwk  bad_3456_551.nwk  good_23456_1.nwk  good_763456_550.nwk
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ (shopt -s nullglob; grep GENE  *_{1..550}.nwk)
good_23456_1.nwk:GENE
good_763456_550.nwk:GENE
```

The unwanted files are excluded and the good names are found.

For comparison, let's try:

```
$ grep "GENE" *[0-9].nwk 
bad_1224_01.nwk:GENE
bad_3456_551.nwk:GENE
good_23456_1.nwk:GENE
good_763456_550.nwk:GENE
```

This matches the unwanted files.